# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"systemUnit")

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"",
>   local:"systemUnit"). Expected elements are
>   <{http://xyz.abc.com/consumer/systems}systemUnit>

Meet an exception when unmarshalling from xml

---

```
 SystemUnit systemUnit;
 {
     final ByteArrayOutputStream originalStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     try {
         final TeeInputStream tee = new TeeInputStream(new FileInputStream("E:/ws/test.xml"), originalStream);

         try {
             final JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(SystemUnit.class);
             final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

             systemUnit = (SystemUnit)unmarshaller.unmarshal(tee);

           System.out.println("Success"); // Pending NO exceptions during processing...

         }
         catch (final javax.xml.bind.JAXBException e) {
             System.out.println("Exception came");
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         finally {
             tee.close();
         }

    //     contactLog.setMessage(originalStream.toByteArray());
     }
     finally {
         originalStream.close();
     }
```

}

---

I have annotation @XmlRootElement(name = "systemUnit") to the systemUnit classs.

can anybody help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to use http://xyz.abc.com/consumer/systems as a default namespace in your xml-file.

xml should contain something like:

```
<systemUnit xmlns="http://xyz.abc.com/consumer/systems">
```

Answer (score 0):

You've configured jaxb for waiting xml element with URI "http://xyz.abc.com/consumer/systems" but i think that in your E:/ws/text.xml there is no uri for elments

So consider different solutions :

**1. If you doesn't want to use URI in XML, reconfigure JAXB in this way**

1.a - If you have generated JAXB beans from xml schema, take a look to

```
elementFormDefault="qualified"
```

and

```
targetNamespace="http://xyz.abc.com/consumer/systems"
```

in the xsd file

1.b - If you have code jaxb bean with annotation directly, consider removing [@XmlType(namespace="http://xyz.abc.com/consumer/systems")](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html) annotation

1.c - Maybe there is a package-info.java file describing the default namespace for tour jaxb beans. Remove it

**2. If you want to use URI in XML : correct your xml test.xml using correct namespace**